# Testing firebase email link in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unit-testing, firebase-authentication

We want to write an automated test to test the authentication flow (email link not password) in an IOS app that uses firebase auth.

If we use the firebase emulator then the callback URL generated is for the web but not for the app.

How can we test 'email link' without using an actual email in an IOS environment?